# calling a dynamic menu from a partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a menu system for my web app, modeled from Paul Sheriff 's course, which works fine. I want to enhance its usability by having specific menus for each subscriber level, as well as for admins. My intent was to have a partial view which would inject the menu html, with that html being derived from the code in a MenuController which calls methods in my MenuService from a services library.

Is this the proper way to go about this? I am new to MVC having been using webforms in the past. If I remove the menu html from my layout page, how is the partialview with the new menu code called? Once that logged in user is logged in and the application knows what menu is required is there a way to cache that layout so the menu doesn't have to be created each page request?

Comment: @downvoter...this is a help site is it not, what exactly is in this question that necessitates a down vote?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I see the problem: it's not clear what you're asking. You refer to a course which is maybe somewhat famous but for many people including me it's unknown. So, it's not clear at all what you have for now. What is that services library? What does MenuService do? How does your menu work for now?

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but please recognize that downvotes are not a punishment. Downvoting simply means that the question is not "good", based on these guidelines: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. If you hover over the downvote arrow on a question, you'll see that descriptions says: "This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful." Your question does not detail any research effort or things you might have already tried (whether you did or did not), and it also is not entirely clear.

Comment: I think this is the course that OP's referencing: http://www.codemag.com/Article/1509031

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what I assume about your case is correct, than you're on the right track. MVC was intended to be used like this.

Complementing Chris Pratt's answer:

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult GetMenu()
{
    // fetch user, subscriber levels, etc.
    return PartialView("_Menu", model);
}
```

You would want to use `[ChildActionOnly]` to prevent server from processing this action method because of response to a client request. With this attribute the partial view will be rendered when it was requested from withing another view.

Given that you have a partial view SubMenu.cshtml, in your MainMenu view or in Layout.cshtml you would have `@Html.RenderPartial("Path_To_SubMenu_View")`

Regarding caching, here is an excerpt from this [blog](http://blog.danielcorreia.net/asp-net-mvc-vary-by-current-user/):

In ASP.NET MVC, the easier way to cache the full rendered page is to use the OutputCacheAttribute, like so:

```
[Authorize]
public class DashboardController : Controller 
{
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
       // Your awesome code goes here
    }
}
```

The previous code would make the Index action stay in cache for one hour. This works great for public content, but for user-specific content you must complement the cache key, so that different users don’t see each-other’s cache.

To do this, we use the VaryByCustom property of the OutputCacheAttribute, like this:

```
[Authorize]
public class DashboardController : Controller 
{
    [OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom = "User")]
    public ActionResult Index() 
    {
       // Your awesome code goes here
    }
}
```

And you also need to handle that “User” value in a method that is called over the HttpApplication: the GetVaryByCustomString method.
So, you need to go to your Global.asax.cs and override that method:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg) 
{ 
    if (arg.Equals("User", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
    {
        var user = context.User.Identity.Name; // TODO here you have to pick an unique identifier from the current user identity
        return string.Format("{0}@{1}", userIdentifier.Name, userIdentifier.Container); 
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg); 
}
```

Or, if you don’t set a custom principal in your pipeline, you can look for the session id like so:

```
private static SessionStateSection SessionStateSection = (System.Web.Configuration.SessionStateSection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("system.web/sessionState");

public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg) 
{ 
    if (arg.Equals("User", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) 
    {
        var cookieName =  SessionStateSection.CookieName;
        var cookie = context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];
        return cookie.Value;
    }

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg); 
}
```

I’m using the session state configuration section to get the session cookie name, so that if you changed the default “ASP.NET_SessionId” it will still work.

Answer (score 2):

You need to utilize a child action:

```
[Authorize]
public class FooController : Controller
{
    ...

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult GetMenu()
    {
        // fetch user, subscriber levels, etc.
        return PartialView("_Menu", model);
    }
}
```

Then, create the view, `Views\Foo\_Menu.cshtml` and utilize the data from the model to determine what menu(s) to show. Finally, in your layout, add the following where you want the menu to appear:

```
@Html.Action("GetMenu", "Foo")
```

To cache the result, you can decorate the child action with `[OutputCache]`, but you need to vary it by the logged in user, so it will be cached for each user uniquely and not shared between multiple users. However, there's no built-in vary by user for output caching, so you have to implement you own.

In Global.asax, add the following:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg)
{
    if (arg == "user")
    {
        return context.User.Identity.Name;
    }
    return string.Empty;
}
```

Then, add the output cache like:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom = "user")]
public ActionResult GetMenu()
```

Note:

1. `FooController` can be whatever controller you like.
2. If the controller is not decorated with `[Authorize]`, then the child action needs to be. Otherwise, you won't have access to the user principal. However, the child action *must* allow anonymous access when used within a layout. Otherwise, you'll end up with infinite redirects on any anonymous pages like login and signup.

Comment: I marked Orifs answer but upvoted you, since he responded first and both answers were similar but i went another route that works fine. Ill post it if you like.